# Show the column and row vertically

Tags: php, mysql

[image: I am getting like this... however i need each data should come with repective columns]The below code explains how the rows and columns are display... i made the column print vertically however the data is not displaying vertically.

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from feb2016.Chargeback_Tracker_2016_February where case_id='$id' and status='Completed'");

    if (!$result) {
        die("Query to show fields from table failed");
    }

    $fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result);

    echo "<table class='gridtable'>";

    for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)
    {
        echo 
        $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
        echo "<td>{$field->name}</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
        echo "<tr>";
            foreach($row as ``$cell)
            echo "<td>$cell</td>";

        echo "</tr>\n";
    }
```

This is what is there
caseid   user   date   status ........
1234      abc    14-03-2016 completed

I want like this

caseid   1234 \n
user     abc \n
date    14-03-2016 \n
status  completed \n

Comment: $cell is value of data fetched from the result query

Comment: **Stop** using deprecated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*` or  `PDO` with prepared statements

Comment: please share sample output . also use mysqli_* or PDO functions

Comment: You miss `<tr>` tag after `echo "<table class='gridtable'>";`

Answer (score 2):

I will offer some general troubleshooting tips for this kind of problem.

The first is View Source in your browser. View Source, sometimes called View Page Source or the like, is your friend! When a web page doesn't render correctly, use it to look at your HTML code. Often you can spot the problem right away.

The second is a text editor that knows HTML. Notepad++ is one such editor, and there are others. Many of them are free (free as in free speech, free as in free kittens). Copy your viewed source and paste it into that editor, and get the editor to tidy up the HTML indentation. Then if you select a closing tag like `</tr>` for example, the editor will highlight the opening tag.

The third is a stylistic suggestion for your php code. It applies also to other web-app languages like PERL and C#. Write your code as a web page, not as a program. This lets you use indentation to show the structure of the HTML your program generates.

For example, the first few lines of your code might look like this, where each closing tag is tab-aligned below its opening tag.

```
 <? $fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result); ?>
 <table class="gridtable">
 <? for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++) { ?>
     <? $field = mysql_fetch_field($result); ?>
     <td> 
        <? $field->name ?>
     </td>
 <? } ?>
</tr>
...
</table>
```

See how the missing `<tr>` becomes easier to spot when you use this technique? What you want is this:

```
 <? $fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result); ?>
 <table class="gridtable">
   <tr>
   <? for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++) { ?>
       <? $field = mysql_fetch_field($result); ?>
       <td>
          <? $field->name ?>
       </td>
   <? } ?>
   </tr>
 ...
 </table>
```

Now, you may protest that all that indentation lards up your web page with extra spaces. This is not a problem, partly because most web servers compress (with Deflate style compression) the HTML they send to browsers. It's also not that much data. Do View Source on this page and you'll discover that Stack Overflow indents their HTML. They know what they're doing. You can do the same.

Comment: This is what is there
caseid   user   date   status ........
1234      abc    14-03-2016 completed

I want like this

caseid   1234
user     abc
date    14-03-2016
status  completed